# How to change username and profile pic on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, android-app

I don't get any option in settings or elsewhere so I can change my profile pic and username. Why?

Comment: Are you using the app? If so, iOS or android? If not the app, on what site exactly you try to change it?

Comment: Don't you see the `Edit Profile & Settings` tab at your [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/376183/user55439)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard i am using app android

Comment: @user0042 no !!!!

Comment: @user55439 no such thing in the app.

Comment: You cannot do anything to update your profile from the App, but you may use Google Chrome -> Open your profile -> Request Desktop Site. Now, you can operate just like you can do on PC. This is only way to edit your profile, using Android Phone.